# Recursive header expansion

Tags: c++, xcode

I have the following warning in my SFML project in Xcode:

[image]

Well, what is the problem here may be? I have to much code, so, I can't post it here.

[image]

On the 2nd image you may may see all of my classes. LightEffect, Background and all other below them inherit LoadingTheSpriteToMain. PlayScreen contains all of them (I mean, #include "LightEffect" and etc.)

Comment: Did you place header guards correctly?

Comment: I think, yes, I have them in every header

Comment: Circular inclusion of headers?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ without seeing the code, are there a recursive number of guesses you can make?

Comment: Well, I've added some more information, maybe It will help to find the problem

Comment: Reduce the problem to a small but complete example, post that. For now voted to close as lacking a **reproducible example**.